# Closure- how can I close over the number of times an inner function rotated a word?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to rotate the letters in the word which is passed to the function like that:
Example: word=helloWorld
    changedWord(1); should return elloWorldh
    changedWord(2); should return lloWorldhe
    etc.

When the word was completely rotated (length of helloWorld is 10, so when calling changedWord(10) it gets completely rotated). Then, I have to switch the direction-meaning 
rotate(1) should return 'DhelloWORL');
rotate(2) should return 'LDhelloWOR';
so now the last letter is being added to the beginning of the word. My code doesn't work and its because I didn't use closure properly-however I don't know what I did wrong.

Any suggestions are very much appreciated!!

```
function rotatingWords(word) {

    var numClosure = 0;
    return function(num) {
        numClosure++;
        if (numClosure <= word.length) {
            return word.slice(num) + word.slice(0, num);

        } else if (numClosure > word.length) {

            return word.slice(3);
        }

    }
}
var changedWord = rotatingWords('helloWORLD');
changedWord(1);
```

Comment: Your code does work, you just haven't added any variable to the closure yet that remembers the direction.

Comment: but isn't that what I did when I defined numClosure outside of the inner function and was incrementing it insight the inner function?

Comment: Yes, but your `slice`ing code does not take the `numClosure` into account.

Comment: Also I'm not sure whether you only want to remember the number of calls, or actually some *position* in the word (how far it is already rotated)

Comment: Ohh thats right-I don't just want to remember the number of calls, I actually want to remember the number (num) because if I call the function lets say 3 times, then the fourth time I call lets say changedWord(10); then I would already want the word to rotate in the other direction. On the other hand I also want to remember the number of times called (so when I call 10 times with changedWord(1); I also want to rotate the other way

Comment: Your examples suggested otherwise - if you call `changedWord(1)` and then `changedWord(2)`, the expected result would be *loWorldhel* already not *lloWorldhe*.

Comment: So maybe you want to work further on the problem a bit yourself? Tip: increase `numClosure` by `num` every time, and treat it as the position in the word. Then (maybe even write a separate function that only takes the word and the position) calculate the result from that only. Then extend that to the case that the position is behind the end of the word.